Get ChosenInlineResult update from channel inline message
I have channel with Sign messages option enable.

And when I try to send inline messages, I don`t recive ChosenInlineResult update, if I send message as channel. I got this update from bot api if I send my inline message as my personal account or if Sign messages option disable in channel. Is this how it's supposed to be or is this a server side bug? My inline feedback in bot settings sets to 100%.
